# Slow image rendering while performing long task on TPL

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, image, task-parallel-library

I am developing a WPF program which performs long running tasks in the background, using TPL's `Parallel.ForEach`.
I have an image control and when am trying to show an image, it seems that the image rendering happens in the thread pool, and since I use it intensively (via TPL Forech) the rendering is extremely slow.
Is there a way to perform the image rendering in higher priority or not in the thread pool ?

Comment: It is not that `Parallel.ForEach` is slow. You may have another process which is consuming high CPU which also have high priority? Otherwise this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I would suspect that your CPU and/or I/O is just saturated...

Answer (score 2):

`Parallel.ForEach` is designed to use as much of your CPU as it can get hold of.  If you don't want it to do that, then either don't use it (just run the long-running task in a single poll thread), or control the amount of your CPU which 'Parallel.ForEach' uses, by [passing in a 'ParallelOptions' object to limit its appetite for CPU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992041.aspx).

You also say you're running 'long running' tasks using Parallel.ForEach - bear in mind that it's designed for getting cpu-bound tasks finished quickly, not backgrounding things which are long-running because they're waiting for I/O (for example).  From the symptoms though, it does sound like you're using it for the right thing, it's just that it's using more CPU than you want.

As far as trying to avoid the thread pool, I think you're barking up the wrong tree - it's just a collection of threads which already exist, designed to avoid the overhead of creating and destroying threads all the time - it's not a priority mechanism - what your two activities are fighting over is access to the CPU, not access to the thread pool.

Comment: can I suspend the work , to let the image rendering use the cpu ? I don't want to reduce the MaxDegreeOfParallelism since i want to use the maximum processing power available.

Comment: It occurs to me that you might be calling Parallel.ForEach from your main user interface thread - you're not doing that are you?  I suppose if you really wanted to pause your Parallel.ForEach operation, you could communicate that to you code which is running in parallel, and that could go to Sleep.  It's a horrible abuse of the thread pool, though.

Comment: no, I call it from a background thread. So do you have any other suggestion how to handle this issue ?  thnaks